# send image from server JAVA to android client using socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, socket.io, serversocket

**when i run the server and the client.. i cant found the image on the sd-card on my android ...  i need help guys**

*i am using android studio and netbeans*
*emphasized text*

**server java code**

```
package javasever;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/**
 *
 * @author METALHEADi
 */
public class JavaSever {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Thread t= new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(400);
                System.out.println("Runnig ........");
                while(true){
                Socket s=ss.accept();
                                    System.out.println("Accept........");
FileInputStream fis =new FileInputStream("D:\\PIC\\all pic\\simo.png");
                        byte[]buffer=new byte [fis.available()];
                        fis.read(buffer);
                        ObjectOutputStream oos =new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                        oos.write(buffer);
                        oos.close();
 s.close();

                    }

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JavaSever.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();













    }

}
```

**client android code**

```
package com.example.metalheadi.androidclient;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText IP,Port,Msg;
    Button Send;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Send= (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        IP= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip_e);
        Port=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.port_e);
        Msg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.msg_e);
        Send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Thread thread =new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Socket socket= new Socket(IP.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(Port.getText().toString()));
//                            DataOutputStream stream =new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
//                            stream.writeUTF(Msg.getText().toString());
//                            stream.flush();
//                            stream.close();



                            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream =new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                           try {
                               byte[] buffer = (byte[]) objectInputStream.readObject();
                               FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("sdcard/simo.png");
                               fileOutputStream.write(buffer);
                           }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }









                            socket.close();






                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                });

                thread.start();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**XML android**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.metalheadi.androidclient.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="IP"
        android:id="@+id/ip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="PORT"
        android:id="@+id/port"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Message"
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_below="@+id/port"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ip_e"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/port_e"
        android:layout_below="@+id/port"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ip_e"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/ip_e" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/msg_e"
        android:layout_below="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/port_e"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/port_e"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SEND"
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_below="@+id/msg_e"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making every mistake in the book here.

1. You are misusing `available()`. See the Javadoc for what it really does, and for a specific warning against the way you are using it.
2. You are assumig that the file size fits an integer.
3. You are assuming that the file fits into memory.
4. You are ignoring the count returned by `read()`.
5. You are writing bytes but reading an object.

All you need is the following copy loop, *without* the object streams:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int count;
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Use this at both ends.